# ¿Como relacionar contenido de un user admin con otros users client?

Tags: java, android, base-de-datos, firebase

es un poco largo de explicar, espero expresarme correctamente.
Estoy trabajando en una app de gestion de informacion de jugadores de voley, esa info es exclusiva para el creador (user admin) y sus entrenadores (user client). Necesito hacer 2 cosas que no encuentro el camino:
(ANDROID STUDIO Y FIREBASE)

1-todos los usuarios (admin y client) comparten 1 parametro que deberia ser el key de relacion entre ellos (CLUB), cuando el user admin crea la info de cada jugador, deberia guardarse en una ruta especifica (para oden en la database), "jugadores"/"club"/"CLUB"(haciendo referencia al valor club de cada user admin). No encuentro la manera de llevar ese valor "CLUB" para que forme parte de la ruta.

2- Los user client solo deben ver esta info, asi que deberian poder ingresar a la info que genero el admin de su respectivo "CLUB" (CLUB que tanto admin y client comparten en su info).

PD: estoy desde el celu, mas tarde puedo mostrar mis codigos.

Estoy usando Realtime Database.

Ese es el FirebaseHelper que uso para Guardar los parametros cargados por el user admin y como recupero el arraylist para la visualizacion desde database:

```
public class FirebaseHelper {
    DatabaseReference DBref;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    Boolean saved;
    ArrayList<Agregar> agregars = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView listView;
    Context c;

    public FirebaseHelper (DatabaseReference DBref, Context context, ListView listView){
        this.DBref = DBref;
        this.c = context;
        this.listView = listView;
        this.retrieve();
    }

    public Boolean save (Agregar agregar){
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if (agregar == null){
            saved = false;
        }else {
            try {
                String userId = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                DBref.child("Jugadores").child("Clubes").child(userId).push().setValue(agregar);
                saved = true;
            } catch (DatabaseException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                saved = false;
            }
        }
        return saved;
    }

    public ArrayList<Agregar> retrieve(){
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        String userId = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DBref.child("Jugadores").child("Clubes").child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                agregars.clear();
                if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0){
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        Agregar agregar = ds.getValue(Agregar.class);
                        agregars.add(agregar);
                    }
                    adapter = new CustomAdapter(c, agregars);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            listView.smoothScrollToPosition(agregars.size());
                        }
                    });
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("mTAG", databaseError.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(c, "ERROR" + databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return agregars;
    }
}
```

Esa es la estructura de mi database:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: escribo aca porque no me da la reputación para comentar. Si alguién, lo ve que lo edite. Aclará por favor si es Realtime o Firestore lo que estás usando. Gracias

Comment: @ptorresi gracias, pero tratemos de respetar las reglas del sitio ;)